# Mensagem de aviso sobre erro na pergunta "tags duplicadas" semi-traduzida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

A mensagem de aviso que aparece quando adicionamos uma tag que diverge de uma existente por uma letra, por exemplo [datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datas) e [data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data), encontra-se parcialmente traduzida:

[image: Captura de Tela]

> Seu ***question*** não pôde ser enviado. Verifique os erros acima.

Da forma que esta palavra aparece aqui sem tradução parece tratar-se de uma mensagem que é comum para perguntas e respostas, onde o sistema aplica "pergunta" ou "resposta" consoante o caso.

Comment: É verdade, que nem [esse](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/935/3117) né?

Comment: @Math Parece estar relacionado sim, _nice catch_ :)

Comment: Quando você tenta editar só as tags, a mensagem é parecida e também tem erro de concordância. Ver screenshot em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458/pedido-de-substituicao-de-tag-editordetexto-para-editor-de-texto

Answer (score 3):

Era basicamente o que o Zuul suspeitava. Revisamos as strings e eu acertei as traduções.

Assim que rolar um build novo, as strings corretas vão pro ar.

Comment: _Cool!_ Quando estiver volta aqui e avisa para eu fechar este assunto :)